# Cycle through the tabs and reformat the columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel document consisting of data imported into multiple tabs. The columns in each tab are stretched out and hard to read.

I am trying to cycle through the tabs and reformat the columns.

```vb
Sub resize_columns()
'cycles through each tab (have to start in first tab)
'selects all columns and autofits them
 
Dim i As Integer

Dim num As Integer

num = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1 'counts number of sheets to use in loop range

For i = 0 To num

    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
    Columns("A:Q").Select
    Columns("A:Q").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
Next i
    
End Sub
```

This code produces

> "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"

The debugger points to the first line inside the For loop.

If I run this code as a test, there is no error:

```vb
Sub resize_columns()
'cycles through each tab (have to start in first tab)
'selects all columns and autofits them

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 2

    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:Q").Select
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:Q").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    
Next i
    
End Sub
```

I have two questions:

1 - How do I loop without the error?
2 - How do I start on the first tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will rarely need to use Select or Activate with Vba

```vb
Sub resize_columns()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      ws.Columns("A:Q").AutoFit
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, understood. Will keep this format in mind for future reference. I was going off of a recorded macro, so that's probably why it looked a bit clunky. This works - thank you so much!

Comment: @arc_user I think your code would work if you change `Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate` to `Sheets(i + 1).Activate`